# android Pass recyclerview item position to dialog button listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Dialog with multiple buttons(cancalButton, deleteButton) is showed when click button in recyclerview item.

So I made two listener(cancelListener, deleteListener).

Show dialog is successful and cancelListener works well, But I can't do what I want in delteListener.

I wanna delete data in firebase when user click delete button in dialog.

So I have to know clicked recyclerview item's position to find data. (Because I can find data by getting key from array.get(position).getTimestamp.

How can I get item position in deleteListener?

```
public class AdapterExplorePlace extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterExplorePlace.ViewHolder> implements Pin_BottomSheetDialog.BottomSheetListener {

ArrayList<ItemExplore> array;
Context context;
private AdapterExplorePlace.RecyclerViewClickListener listener;
private DialogDeletePin dialog;
DatabaseReference pinRef;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

String currentPage;
@ColorInt int starColor;
@ColorInt int startextColor;

public AdapterExplorePlace(ArrayList<ItemExplore> array, Context context, AdapterExplorePlace.RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
    this.array = array;
    this.context =context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterExplorePlace.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    starColor = sharedPreferences.getInt("starColor", 0);
    startextColor = sharedPreferences.getInt("startextColor", 0);
    currentPage = sharedPreferences.getString("currentPage", "");
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_explore_place,parent,false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    pinRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pinData").child(mAuth.getUid()).child(currentPage);

    return new AdapterExplorePlace.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterExplorePlace.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(array.get(position).getThumbnail() == null){
        holder.explorePlaceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.defalut_place_image);
    }
    else{
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(array.get(position).getThumbnail())
                .centerCrop()
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(holder.explorePlaceImage);
    }

    holder.explorePlaceRegion.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getPlaceAddress()));
    holder.explorePlaceCategory.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getPlaceCategory()));
    holder.explorePlaceName.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getPlaceName()));
    holder.explorePlaceStyle.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getPlaceStyle()));
    holder.explorePlaceVisitedMember.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getMember()));
    holder.explorePlaceStyle.setTextColor(starColor);
    holder.timestamp=String.valueOf(array.get(position).getTimestamp());

    Drawable styleDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.rounded);
    styleDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(starColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    holder.explorePlaceStyle.setBackground(styleDrawable);

    
    pinRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot pinCheckSnap : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d("####Icon Check", String.valueOf(String.valueOf(pinCheckSnap.getValue()).contains(holder.timestamp)));

                if(String.valueOf(pinCheckSnap.getValue()).contains(holder.timestamp)){
                    holder.btnExplorePlacePin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_scrap_active);
                    holder.btnExplorePlacePin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            openDialog(position);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    holder.btnExplorePlacePin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_scrap_inactive);
                    holder.btnExplorePlacePin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("timestamp", holder.timestamp);
                            Pin_BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new Pin_BottomSheetDialog();
                            bottomSheet .setArguments(args);
                            bottomSheet.show(((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "pinBottomSheet");
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return array.size();
}

@Override
public void onButtonClicked(String text) {
}


public interface RecyclerViewClickListener{
    void onClick(View v, int position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView explorePlaceImage;
    TextView explorePlaceRegion;
    TextView explorePlaceCategory;
    TextView explorePlaceName;
    TextView explorePlaceStyle;
    TextView explorePlaceVisitedMember;
    String timestamp;
    ImageButton btnExplorePlacePin;

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        explorePlaceImage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceImage);
        explorePlaceRegion =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceRegion);
        explorePlaceCategory =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceCategory);
        explorePlaceName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceName);
        explorePlaceStyle =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceStyle);
        explorePlaceVisitedMember =itemView.findViewById(R.id.explorePlaceVisitedMember);
        btnExplorePlacePin =itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnExplorePlacePin);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition());
    }

    void setItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
}

private void openDialog(final int position){
    dialog = new DialogDeletePin(context,cancelListener, deleteListener);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    dialog.show();
}
View.OnClickListener cancelListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener deleteListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //I need to know item position for deleting data.
        Log.d("####dialog","click delete");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};

}
```

DeleteDialogPin

```
class DialogDeletePin extends Dialog {

private Button btnCancelDeletePin;
private Button btnDeletePin;

private View.OnClickListener cancelListener;
private View.OnClickListener deleteListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // 다이얼로그 외부 화면 흐리게 표현
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lpWindow = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lpWindow.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    lpWindow.dimAmount = 0.6f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lpWindow);

    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_delte_pin);

    btnCancelDeletePin = findViewById(R.id.btnCancelDeletePin);
    btnCancelDeletePin.setOnClickListener(cancelListener);

    btnDeletePin = findViewById(R.id.btnDeletePin);
    btnDeletePin.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);


    //클릭이벤트
}
public DialogDeletePin(Context context, View.OnClickListener canceltListener, View.OnClickListener deleteListener) {
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    this.cancelListener = canceltListener;
    this.deleteListener = deleteListener;
}

}
```

Comment: Haven’t looked at the entire code but doesn’t the argument in private void openDialog(final int position) have the item position?

Comment: @lyncs Hello lyncs. Yes I added that. But I don't know How can I pass that to delteListener

Comment: Can you show your code for DialogDeletePin

Comment: @lyncx Now I add DialogDeltePin code!

Comment: I solved it thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method `private void openDialog(final int position)` has the position information. One of the way you can do it is just by creating a class for deleteListemer (DeleteListenerWithItemPos) and then pass the `position` as an argument at the constructor.

An example of how to implement is shown as follows:

```
private void openDialog(final int position){
    deleteListener = new DeleteListenerWithItemPos(position);
    dialog = new DialogDeletePin(context,cancelListener, deleteListener);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    dialog.show();
}

View.OnClickListener deleteListener;

public static class DeleteListenerWithItemPos implements View.OnClickListener() {

    private int itemPos;

    public DeleteListenerWithItemPos(int itemPos){
        this.itemPos = itemPos;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {=
        itemPos; //get itemPos here
        Log.d("####dialog","click delete");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I applied it to my code and show error..Is it right to add this code in same java file?

Comment: You're welcome! Could you help me too marked this as accepted answer? Thanks!